# What is the probability that a rod can be cut with the length of cut being 5 units?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

A rod of length 10 units and breadth 3 units is cut as shown in figure. Assuming that the longest cut can be from A to C and B to D. What is the probability that the cut made is of length 5 units. The cut can be made anywhere i.e. it is not restricted just at the middle. For ex- A cut of length 5 unit may start from A and end on the line CD.

[image: A figure depicting the situation]

Comment: The probability of the cut being exactly 5 units is zero, as it is for any specific value from a continuous distribution.

Comment: Can we say that the cut is made with a uniformly distributed choice of angle and point on the rod?

Comment: What would be the approach if we wanted the probability for a range say from 4.5 units to 5.5 units.

Comment: In that case you need to decide what the random process is for selecting the cut.  See, for example, [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).